# Is it possible to get the information stored in "General->Network->cellular data network" programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is it possible? I need it for an application that checks if this data is correct.

Comment: @Nick Cellular data and MMS settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot check the stored system settings manually. However, you can use Apple's Reachability class and the UIMessageComposer class to check (ay least most of) what you need.

Comment: Ok. I can indeed use the Reachability class to check if there is an internet connection, thanks for the suggestion! I guess checking if MMS is correctly set up will involve some more work, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for this.

The info is written in plists in the file system (take a look at SpyPhone if you want to know more: https://github.com/nst/spyphone/), but in my opinion that's the wrong way to go.

Comment: ok thanks, yea i don't think spyPhone is the right way to go, but good to know :)